# How to create multiple database users on AWS?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

When you create an database on AWS (basically any type) you create a master account for the database. Does anyone know how to create secondary accounts, possibly specify permissions, with different usernames and passwords?

Comment: IAM service let you do that.

Comment: I think this documentation from AWS is what you need. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/

Comment: This varies enormously depending upon the database being used. Which database are you wanting to use? RDS (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MariaDB), Aurora (MySQL, PostgreSQL), DynamoDB, Redshift, DocumentDB, ElastiCache, Neptune, Timestream, Quantum Ledger?